# How to route request from one application pool to another in iis 6.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, w3wp

I have got two web applications (separate virtual directories) residing in the DefaultAppPool on Windows Server 2003. My first application has got a link and when I click on it, the second application opens up.

Now I want to use different .Net framework for both web applications and for that in IIS 6.0, I will have to host them in separate app pools.

Now the question is - is it possible to host them in different app pools and keep the behavior intact so that if I click on the link in first web application, it can still open the second web application hosted in a different app pool?

Thanks in advance,

D

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution and it is simpler than what I actually thought.

Steps I took:

1. Create another app pool in IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003
2. Assign one of the web applications to this pool. So now I have two web applications in two different app pools. Currently both are having ASP.NET version as 2.0.50727
3. Change the ASP.NET version of one of the applications to 4.0.30319. So interesting fact to understand here is - in IIS 6, you can't set the .NET framework for an app pool. It actually assumes it from the first application in it and then applies it to all the web applications residing in this app pool
4. And it is done!!
5. It can be checked to list all the sites and which .NET versions they are configured to by using aspnet_iisreg -lk. Run this command from your .NET framework directory. For ex: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
6. Both the sites with different .NET framework will be listed

Hope this helps.